# Same ID for two folders with different "displayName"

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I made a request to this API and got `msgfolderroot` ID:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/msgfolderroot
```

After that, I made a call and got a list of folders:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/root/childFolders
```

I needed to find a `msgfolderroot` in the root directory, so I copied the ID of the desired folder from the first query and searched in the response of the second request, as the result I found that two folders can have one ID.

Please, tell me, how is this possible? And, please, describe why `childFolderCount` and  `totalItemCount` of these two folders different?

**Examples**

Response from first request:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('9ee07cfe-3e76-4005-bd2b-258f31aaea72')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEIAAA=",
    "displayName": "Корневой уровень хранилища",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEBAAA=",
    "childFolderCount": 20,
    "unreadItemCount": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 0,
    "wellKnownName": "msgfolderroot"
}
```

Folders with same IDs in response of the second request:

```
{
  "id": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEiAAA=",
  "displayName": "XrmActivityStream",
  "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEBAAA=",
  "childFolderCount": 0,
  "unreadItemCount": 0,
  "totalItemCount": 25,
  "wellKnownName": null
},

...

{
  "id": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEIAAA=",
  "displayName": "Корневой уровень хранилища",
  "parentFolderId": "AAMkAGNjZjYwNmU4LTJjYWUtNDJiNC1hNWNhLWMwNzllZWZkMjM0NAAuAAAAAAAJFA5toPC1R7wN_YNAZc4HAQAYGWCmW3joQLGNsVuMcOgpAAAAAAEBAAA=",
  "childFolderCount": 20,
  "unreadItemCount": 0,
  "totalItemCount": 0,
  "wellKnownName": "msgfolderroot"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two IDs are not quite identical. The first ends in `iAAA=` the second ends in `IAAA=`.

The answer for `childFolderCount` and `totalItemCount` being different between the folders is simply because they are different folders and so can have different counts of items and folders within them.

Although this question is several years old, this is one of the first results for those seeking help when they appear to have duplicate mailFolder IDs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).